# Do some action before application install in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am using C# and .NET 4.0 framework to develop a WPF application. I need to perform a task like this: Before installing my WPF application on the  desktop, I need to remove some folder in that installing desktop. I tried the below one in:

#### File installer.cs

```
this.BeforeInstall +=new InstallEventHandler(Installer_BeforeInstall);

void Installer_BeforeInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    // Code
}
```

Whatever code I used in the above methods to remove the folder/directory are executed after my WPF application installed, means in half of the installation. I need to remove the folder before the WPF application saves the installation folder on my desktop. How do I do this in C# using .NET 4.0?

Update: installer.cs

```
namespace namespace name
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public Installer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall);

            this.BeforeUninstall += new InstallEventHandler(ServiceInstaller_BeforeUninstall);
        }

        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);
        }

        void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            //code
        }

        void ServiceInstaller_BeforeUninstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            // Code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a suggestion: Use a framework like WIX (free) to make your installer. Installing something is a complicated task, especially if something unexpected happens. WiX needs some time to understand, but is very powerful

Comment: What are you using to install the application? InstallShield, Wix, ClickOnce, xcopy, ... ??

Comment: @Mrchief I am using VS2010 to build the solution.MSI file is generated and i am using that msi file to instal.

Comment: Any chance you can post in the full `installer.cs` code?

Comment: I think your best bet is to use a pure msi solution.  there is a removefile table.  Use orca to do this see http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/how-remove-folder-uninstall-was-not-created-install

Comment: @Joe I want to uninstall a application on installation of my msi file and remove some unwanted folder from directory.Can you tell me how to do this.

Comment: that link has a vbscript file that you should be able to adapt.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting files/folder on target systems is dangerous and should be avoided. You should only delete files that *you* create; you being your MSI file here. Now that you have been warned, here are your options:

- Using a Visual Studio Setup project, this is not possible, or at least not trivial. You need to implement a custom action using C++, compile into a DLL, build you MSI, [change the install sequence using Orca](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/system/files/images/Orca.gif) to run before `CostFinalize`.
- Use a third-party tool to give more power to installer projects, such as [AdvancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-remove-file-or-folder.html)
- If you *do* decide to go third party, I would say use WiX. Look at [RemoveFolder](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefolder.html) action or you can use a `CustomAction` like this:

  ```
  <CustomAction Id="DeleteFiles" Return="check" Value="del path\to\folder" />

  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="DeleteFiles" After='InstallFinalize'>Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
    ...
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
  ```

Comment: I want to uninstall an existing application on installation of my msi file.How to do this using Wix tool.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483669/wix-uninstall-different-product and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025798/wix-uninstall-product-using-command-line-during-installation